# How to Read the Object for post requests in Spring Data JPA REST?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, spring-data-rest

I am using `Spring Data JPA`, `REST` along with `H2` database. I am able to create data & save to database with the help of `commandline runner` and i'm able to read the data with the `GET` request.

However i am not able to post the data using `POST` Request.

Here down is my Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/create"}, produces = "application/json",consumes = "application/json")
public Customer createCustomer(@RequestBody Customer cust) {
    System.out.println("new Customer to be added is :" + cust.toString());
    repository.save(cust);
    System.out.println("added Successfully");
    return cust;
}
```

Can anyone help me here?

Customer Entity looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
    protected Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']", id, firstName, lastName);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Tried passing customer object with and without id but none of them worked. tried passing

```
{"firstName":"Michelle","lastName":"Swepson"}
```

While fetching all i got is

```
{"id":6,"firstName":null,"lastName":null} & the passed customer object is
```

Not getting read by api..as i could see the object as

```
{"id":null,"firstName":null,"lastName":null}
```

Comment: Can you show me your `Service` and `Repository` and `application.properties`?

Comment: I Autowired the the repository from controller itself.. & application.properties is empty.
Repository looks like
    
    public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

 List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);

 Optional<Customer> findById(long id);

    }

Comment: Hi @FaeemazazBhanej, Issue sorted out.. issue was with RequestBody annotation
i used the wrong one io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody
instead of org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody

Answer (score 1):

issue was with RequestBody annotation.i did use the wrong one io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody instead of org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on the entity. You should generate setter for attribute id .

```
public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
}
```

When you send the request body, don't send the id because it is generate automatically.

```
{"firstName":"Michelle","lastName":"Swepson"}
```

You can also add the lombok dependency to your project to generate the getter, setter, constructors, etc. with just an annotation.

Comment: it's not working even after setter created for id.. it seems  somehow the api is not properly reading the data. i tried printing the cust object on console before calling repository.save(cust) and i could see the below.
 Customer[id=null, firstName='null', lastName='null']

Comment: If `id` generate automatically then why would he want to make setter for `id` data member.